# Chrome's Webdriver getting stuck on driver.get(URL)

Tags: python-3.x, undetected-chromedriver

```
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--excludeSwitches=enable-automation")
    options.add_argument("--excludeSwitches=enable-logging")
    prefs = {
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False
    }
    }
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'dismiss')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(80)
    # Set the script timeout to 20 seconds
    driver.set_script_timeout(30)
```

This is my code that I am using. But Script running after some time chrome driver is stuck. New iteration can not executed (stuck on `driver.get(URL)`). I am facing this problem recently.

Answer (score 0):

Your webdriver needs the chromedriver itself. You can download it here

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection

according to your Chrome browser's version.

Then create a service and indicate the absolute path to the chromedriver.

```
service = Service('<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>')
driver = uc.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Here is the whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--excludeSwitches=enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--excludeSwitches=enable-logging")
prefs = {
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False
    }
}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'dismiss')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')

service = Service('D:\\DEV\\chromedriver.exe')  # Enter your own path to chromedriver here
driver = uc.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(80)

# Set the script timeout to 20 seconds
driver.set_script_timeout(30)

url = '<YOUR_URL>'
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: undetected-chromedriver automatically download the latest version of chrome.
so, I hope don't need  "service".

Comment: Well, but this one does not stuck on driver.get()

Answer (score 0):

- first use try-except block in your code like so:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    driver.get(URL)
except TimeoutException as e:
    print(f"Page load timed out: {e}")
```

- Check for JavaScript Errors in the console
- try headless mode and check if it works.
- if none of the above works, enable logging for the driver to see more info.